# starting problem citroen berlingo van

Tags: starting

I have a 1999 LX 1.9 citroen berlingo mk1 panel van(M49)
For quite a while the ignition has had to be turned 3-4 times, before the circuit responds, and fires the starter, the igntion sw wiring , and starter solenoid have been replaced, but not the sw itself.
 Yesterday i went to the vehicle, and on turning the igntion switch on, the orange heater plug light came on for a flash second, there was an audible click from under the bonnet nearside, and although the engine turns over, it refuses to start, i have checked all fuses, and cleaned all visible earthing points, any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to offer something solid here.

You could use old faithful process of elimination, and disconnect the wiring from the switch, and manually hotwire it. This would prove the switch is contacting adequately.

Failing that, are you sure the battery is ok? Maybe check the battery clamps are tight, clean, and battery posts free of acid corrosion.